# Is it possible to use an ed25519 security key with Google Chrome SSH applets?

Tags: chrome, ecc, openssh, u2f, ecdsa

After generating an OpenSSH EC key on a hardware security key:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C comment
```

Is it possible to use this key with Google Chrome [SSH applet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd) or [Mosh](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/iodihamcpbpeioajjeobimgagajmlibd), in particular on non-Linux machines where there is no `ssh` command available with proper HW key support?